# how to stop sessions expiring after every 3-5 minutes

Tags: php

i have sessions for user login in my web sites but it expires after every 3-5 mintues and often in just 30-45 seconds... how can i fix that

Comment: Is the session ID always the same?

Comment: How are you testing if your session has expired? How are you creating your sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be variable, it is either a set amount or something is changing it. You can change these values in php.ini or with an .htaccess file if your hosting supports it.